# Get a list of friends in Google Plus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-plus

How do I get a list of friends (name and image URL) for a current_user? I am using FB and G+ for authentication. I was able to get the list of friends for users who've logged in via FB connect.

I've found **[google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)** gem, but I don't know how to use it for this situation. There's also [**this**](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) official link.

user.rb

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
       end
  end 

    def fbfriends
     @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
        begin
          @fbfriends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields: "id")
          @uids = @fbfriends.map{ |v| v.values }.flatten
        rescue Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError => e
          redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
        end
          @friends = User.where(uid: @uids)
    end
```

omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'xxx', 'xxx',{
    :image_size => 'large'
    }
  provider :google_oauth2, 'xxx', 'xxx',{
      :image_aspect_ratio => "original",
      :image_size => 200
    }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to request access to the user's visible circles using the login scope and then perform an API call to plus.people.list for the collection `visible`.

For a working demo of how to use the API from Ruby, check the [Google+ Ruby Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ruby). For a sample integrating rails, check out the [Photohunt Ruby sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-photohunt-server-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack/workaround:

1. Add Birthdays Calendar to your Google Calendar
2. Select 'Display Only This Calendar'
3. View Calendar as Agenda

This is far from perfect, but it's a simple workaround to get your connections as a list.